# How to access network drive in python script and automatically run it when user logout?

Tags: python, automation, windows-server, network-drive

I have a python script that needs to run every hour to upload local files to a shared drive, but the script won't run when I log out from the remote **windows server**(I have admin access to both the network drive and server), is there a way to let it run every hour automatically without user login?

Comment: What OS has the remote server? Linux?

Comment: it's windows server@andreis11

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution for Linux:

You can create a bash script to run a python file and create a cronjob to run that bash script.

Your bash script going to look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
python location/of/your_script.py
```

save as automate.sh and give the permissions to run this script automatically:

```
sudo chmod +x location/of/your_script.py
sudo chmod +x location/of/your_bash_script.sh
```

After that we have to create the cronjob you can use this link to create a suitable cronjob for you.

https://crontab-generator.org/

And we need to add that cronjob in the list:

```
crontab -e
```

When you open this cronjob editor, put your cronjob at the bottom and save it please. It should run without a problem.

This is the solution for Windows Server:

For Windows you need to create a .bat script for execution.

automate.bat script going to look like:

```
C:\your\python\executable\path\python.exe "C:/your/python/file/path/you/want/to/execute/your-python-script.py"
pause
```

Set permissions for .bat file with GUI:

1. Right click the .bat file
2. Click to 'Properties'
3. Click 'Security' on the top bar
4. Make sure your user has the 'FULL' permissions if it is not give the 'FULL' permissions.

Set permissions with console in Windows:

1. Open the console
2. Enter the code below in the console

Note: Make sure you run the console with 'admin' privileges in Windows.

```
icacls c:\your\bat\file\path\automate.bat /grant YourUser:F
```

After this step, you need to create a "Task Schedular" entry. In Windows you can use "TASK SCHEDULAR" tool to automate your tasks.

When you create the TASK, in Task Scheduler go in 'Task Schedular Library' and follow the steps below:

1. Right click your task
2. Click Properties
3. In the 'GENERAL' tab you should able to see 'Security' settings, make sure your USER is specified there.
4. Activate the 'RUN USER IS LOGGED ON OR NOT' option
5. Also check the 'Configure For' option
6. After these go in to 'Actions' tab on top tab bar
7. Click to 'Edit'
8. Edit the 'Start In' option with your .bat file's main folder location. Ex: c:\your\bat\file\path\

After all these steps, I was able to run my script without any problem on my Windows Virtual Machine. However environmantal differences may cause a problem, please comment your experience.

Comment: thanks for your solution, it's my fault that i didnt say it's windows server.

Comment: @tysss I just added the Windows version. You may do not know how 'task schedular' works, however I am pretty sure there are a lot of good videos about that process on YouTube. But please comment for further needs.

Comment: thanks, I tried to use .bat file in task scheduler but it didnt work.@kopmaz

Comment: @tysss I did create a VM with Windows 10 and tried to experience your issue. I was not able to experience 'permissions' issue, however I want to update my answer with an 'set the permissions' informations. It may help you.